# MVVM delete selected viewmodel from database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im using the mvvm pattern. I can select a viewmodel from a list of items, when running a command I want to delete this item.

For this projects I have two repositorys (and one interface) EquipmentRepository and DummyEquipmentRepository,  the EquipmentRepository  is connected to a database and has a method delte (implemented from the interface) like:

```
    public void DeleteItem(Equipment obj)
    {
        var db = new AppContext();
        db.Equipment.Remove(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However in my viewmodel I select equipmentViewModels instead of objects, how should I pass the selected Object instead of the viewmodel?

Im trying to run in my viewmodel

```
    myData.DeleteItem(SelectedEquipment);
```

but this needs an Equipment object instead of the EquipmentViewModel

Comment: Is the selected object stored within the EquipmentViewModel? If so, then pass the EquipmentViewModel to the method and have the method extract the object from the viewmodel. The method's signature will be like "public static void DeleteItem(this EquipmentViewModel viewModel)"

Comment: In addition you could only extract the id and then pass it to the repository DeleteItem by id overload, I always have both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple and obvious: Create it.

```
myData.DeleteItem(new Equipment 
{
    EquipmentId = SelectedEquipment.EquipmentId
});
```

or expand your Repository to delete by Id

```
public void DeleteItem(Equipment obj)
{
    var db = new AppContext();
    db.Equipment.Remove(obj);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

public void DeleteItemById(int equipmentId)
{
    var equipment = new Equipment 
    { 
        EquipmentId = equipmentId
    };

    // this should really be done in the constructor, as you want to keep the context for the lifetime of your repository, which should encompass a unit of work 
    var db = new AppContext(); 
    db.Equipment.Attach(equipment);
    db.Equipment.Remove(equipment);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Edit:**
Since it seems you're using Entity Framework the above should work. Of course you can first fetch the object by Id and then pass it to `DeleteItem`.

Alternative ways are

```
public void DeleteItemById(int equipmentId)
{
    var db = new AppContext();
    var equipment = db.Equipment.Where( e => e.EquipmentId == equipmentId);
    db.Equipment.Remove(equipment);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```